# Display Popup by clicking Image (for Multiple image)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried for single image, for on click image, respective image popup window appears but same i want it for multiple images as i dont want to write js individually for each image..

as i have multiple images individually if i click on each of them popup window will appear as popup image & the image which i clicked is not same... Hence popup image source file is different

**Expected output**

[image]

**Reference**

**I Tried**
Below what are tried using HTML, CSS  & JS

**HTML**

```
 <img id="myImg" class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg">
                                                    <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content"  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQS2ol73JZj6-IqypxPZXYS3rRiPwKteoD8vezk9QsRdkjt3jEn&usqp=CAU">


  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style> 
#myImg {

  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}


#myImg2 {

  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg2:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

</style>
```

**JS**

```
<script>

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Shahbazmak/pen/qBOvgdv)

Comment: did you saw that your using two different url for one image?
also why don't you just create a function to handle the modal effect for multiple images?

Comment: hi @Deniz,i have edited expected output

Comment: Can you add more images in your example and reproduce your issue?

Comment: hi @Deniz, i have edited Codepen link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I edited your codepen a bit. So what I done:

- removed your on click handler
- added one handler for all clicks
- applied it only for your images
- added `id` for `modal-img`

I don't recommend you to use multiple ids with the same value. Would be better to use classes instead

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
// var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("modal-img");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
// img.onclick = function(){
//   modal.style.display = "block";
//   modalImg.src = this.src;
//   captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
// }


document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const elem = e.target;
  if (elem.id==="myImg") {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = elem.dataset.biggerSrc || elem.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = elem.alt; 
  }
})

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {

  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}


#myImg2 {

  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg2:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img style="width:30%" id="myImg" class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"
data-bigger-src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg"
>

 <img style="width:28%"  id="myImg" class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/21/24/the-road-815297__340.jpg">
 <img style="width:29%"  id="myImg" class="img-fluid" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg">

                                                    <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img id="modal-img" class="modal-content"  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQS2ol73JZj6-IqypxPZXYS3rRiPwKteoD8vezk9QsRdkjt3jEn&usqp=CAU">
    
  
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want same image should magnify same result, but for example in gmail we have image (small size but not all content in it) as an attachment if we click on that it shows bigger & enlarged detailed in it

Comment: @zab you could add to img element your custom data attribute with second img src. I add it to the first image in the snippet. Is it what you want?

Comment: say for example in Gmail account, when we see any image attachement its a type of crop image before clicking on it, when we click on that it will become full image, so there are two images one is croped one and another one is a full or actual image, i want to accomplish same over here

Comment: So you need just put two versions of each image at your server. Add a link for a smaller one to src and for bigger to data-bigger-src `<img src='/images/img1_small.jpg' data-bigger-src='/images/img1_big.jpg' />`